# How can find my Amazon EC2 Bridge with Globe

Tags: bridge, ec2

I installed a cloud bridge on Amazon EC2. Now I wanted to find it using Globe (http://globe.rndm.de/). But what name do I search for? I didn't choose one.

Answer (score 3):

You can either search for bridges by nickname, or hashed fingerprint.  The nickname starts with `ec2bridge`, and the hashed fingerprint is a 40-character hex string.  Here's a Globe query for all EC2 bridges http://globe.rndm.de/#/search/query=ec2bridge that should include your bridge, too.

Now, I'm not sure what's the easiest way to find out either nickname or hashed fingerprint of your EC2 bridge.  You'll probably have to log into your EC2 instance and look up either information.  But I can't give you a howto for that right now.  (Maybe somebody else who's running an EC2 bridge can step in here?)

Answer (score 2):

Globe, and similar sites, will only return results for Tor relays (that is, servers that are listed in publicly available consensus documents). Tor bridges are never included in these documents (if they were, they would be easier to block).

Comment: Actually, Globe shows bridge details, but without IP addresses and other sensitive details that would make them easier to block.

Comment: Oh, it would be great if the site had a short explanation of how to search for bridges and not just relays. I can't be the only one who searches for a bridge the same way I would search for a relay.

Answer (score 1):

Your bridge's nickname is found in `/etc/tor/torrc` on your ec2 instance (log in with ssh to get here, then type `cat /etc/tor/torrc`).

I found this information here:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/How_to_Protect_your_Internet_Anonymity_and_Privacy/Your_own_TOR_node_on_Amazon_EC2

You can then search for this nickname in [Globe](http://globe.rndm.de/) (though you may have to wait about a day for it to show up).

Answer (score 0):

You can search on Globe by the IP Address of your bridge node. You should be able to find that information in the EC2 management console.

Comment: I tried and it doesn't find it. Though I can use it with my tor. Does it mean that it is not public?

Comment: Searching for bridges by IP address does not work, because IP addresses are redacted from bridge descriptors before handing them over to Onionoo/Globe.

Comment: Ah, Fair enough. I didn't realise this, although it's obvious in retrospect